# Apache camel bean state is lost

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a route

```
    from("timer://poller?fixedRate=true&period=1500")
            .routeId("db-poller")
            .filter(method(StateBean.class, "doProcess"))
            .to("direct:ready-to-process").end();

     from("direct:ready-to-process")
            .bean(StateBean.class, "setDoProcess(false)");
```

my StateBean looks like this

```
@Component
public class StateBean {

    private final AtomicBoolean process =
            new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public boolean doProcess() {
        return process.get();
    }

    public void setDoProcess(boolean state) {
        process.set(state);
    }

}
```

My expectations are for bean to preserve process state as false, but on the second loop
for some reason the state comes back to true. What I'm doing wrong?

**NOTES**

this route, however works as intended if I make `process` variable static

is there any way to make it work without a static field `process`, or without
an external source (i.e. DB)

**OTHER NOTES**

I'm using

Apache Camel 3.10.0

spring-boot 2.5

**UPDATE NO.1**

For the sake of full solution, thanks to Luca Burgazzoli
I did something like this

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private StateBean state;

    @Autowired
    public MyRoute(StateBean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
    
    from("timer://poller?fixedRate=true&period=1500")
            .routeId("db-poller")
            .filter(exchange -> state.doProcess())
            .to("direct:ready-to-process").end();

     from("direct:ready-to-process")
            .process(exchange -> state.setDoProcess(false))
            .process(...)
            .process(...)
            .split(...)
            .streaming()
            .to(...)
            .process(exchange ->  state.setDoProcess(true))
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sharing a specific bean instance as the call bean(StateBean.class, ...) are supposed to create a new instance of the bean of the required class

You should use something like .beanRef("name-of-the-bean", ....)